# FOSJsRouting bundle returns error No route found for "GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, twig, url-routing

I have this table in my twig view:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data 1</th>
      <th>Data 2</th>
      <th>DETAILS</th>
      <th>EDIT</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for pc in arrayPointComptage %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ pc.data1}}</td>
        <td>{{ pc.data2}}</td>
        <td>
          <a><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs showDetail" href="{{ path('detailsPointsComptage', {'id': pc.id }) }}">Detail</button></a>
          <a href="{{ path('editPointsComptage', {'id': pc.id }) }}"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</button></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

<dialog id="window" title="detail pc"></dialog>
```

I am using [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), in order to use route with ajax method.

When I click on the detail button, it returns me in a dialog tag with all detail I need.

This is the javascript code in order to retuns me the details in a dialog window:

```
// dialog window behavior
(function() {
    var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
    // Array of the buttons.
    var showButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('showDetail');
    // Event handler
    var showDialog = function() {
      // Now you have to use the show button as base , to find the data you want to display...
      console.log(this);
      dialog.show();
    };
    var i, len = showButtons.length;
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        showButtons[i].onclick = showDialog;
    }
})();

//jax with FOSJsRouting
  $('.showDetail').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      'url': Routing.generate('detailsPointsComptage', {'id': $(this).val()}),
      'success': function(loadDetail) {
          $('#window').html(loadDetail);
      }
    });
  });
```

Following the documentation, I expose my route to true argument in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
fos_js_routing:
    routes_to_expose: [ detailsPointsComptage ]
```

And to be sure in my `routing.yml`:

```
detailsPointsComptage:
    path:  /my/path/to/detail/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:MyController:detailsPointsComptage }
    requirements:
    methods: GET
    options:
        expose: true
```

When i click on the detail button, I have this error:

> No route found for "GET /my/path/to/detail"

In the browser, with right click I can inspect all element. On the console tab I have this:

> `<button class=​"btn btn-info btn-xs showDetail"`
>   `href=​"/​symfony_app/​web/​my/​path/to/​detail/​1">​Detail​</button>​` 
>   `http://localhost/symfony/web/my/path/to/detail` Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Indeed, if I follow the link `http://localhost/symfony/web/my/path/to/detail`, I have the error of route not found for GET, but if I write this url `http://localhost/symfony/web/my/path/to/detail/1` it returns me the right view.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Because you haven't that route without id, you get val() but you haven't value on button. Even you don't need this bundle because you can get href value from button.

Comment: @malcolm tank you for answer me, you allow me to understand where the problem was. I understand now, that the route could not be without the id parameter.

Comment: It can be without parameter, but you must set `id` in defaults section of route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route needs the `id` parameter, it is required, so this behaviour is normal.

The problem is that your `$(this).val()` doesn't return the `id` as you expect, you should do something like this instead, since the route is already generated in the `href` attribute of your button :

```
$('.showDetail').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      'url': $(this).attr('href'),
      'success': function(loadDetail) {
          $('#window').html(loadDetail);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

NB : using href for a `<button>` doesn't really make any sense, you should use a `<a>` (or use another attribute like `data-link` for instance) :

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-xs showDetail" href="{{ path('detailsPointsComptage', {'id': pc.id }) }}">Detail</a>
```

Comment: thank you a lot, your answer is the good one, I understand well about what you say concerning the button, I change it in my code.